# Batch File to store backup files with timestamps

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup, cmd

I have two folders in the same drive. I want to create backup of an access database. I need to copy the main file, append the name with the date and time and store it in a different folder.

Source Folder: `G:\PMO\Talent Mgt\Data`
Source file: `Talent_Management_Data.accdb`

Destination File: `G:\PMO\Talent Mgt\Archive\Talent_Management_Data.accdb_20120101`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064557/creating-a-filename-as-a-timestamp-in-a-batch-job

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `for` command to execute `copy` for each file. A simple batch file would be:

```
cd "G:\PMO\Talent Mgt\Data"
for %%A in (*.accdb) do copy %%A ..\Archive\%%A_%date:-=%
```