# Filename timestamp in Windows CMD batch script getting truncated

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script that outputs a file, and I'm trying to ensure that each time the script is executed, no existing files are overwritten, so I'm trying to put a timestamp on it.

Currently I have this:

```
set  stamp=%DATE:/=-%_%TIME::=-%
```

But if the time is 1-9 AM, it gives something like:

```
13-06-2012_ instead of a full 13-06-2012_12-39-37.28
```

How can I fix this?

I'm using Windows 7, and the output of `echo %date% %time%` in a command line window is (my clock format for 'short date' is set to display 3-letter months):

```
03-Sep-12 9:06:21.54
```

Basically I want a solution that solves the issue regardless of what the clock  format is set to.

---

**Edit:** Since no one likes to read past the title, I will explicitly state this question is about a truncation issue. And I found a solution.

I've been using the following timestamp for a good while now, works well.

```
set timestamp=%DATE:/=-%_%TIME::=-%
set timestamp=%timestamp: =%
```

It produced a timestamp like: `18-03-2013_13-37-43.26`, by replacing `/` and `:` in `%TIME%` and `%DATE%`, then stripping white space. The whitespace was the problem in my original question, really.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get current date/time on the Windows command line in a suitable format for usage in a file/folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-date-time-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format)

Comment: @feeela That does not solve or explain the truncation issue. See [my accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11038702/815680).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [an answer to Stack Overflow quesion *Creating a file name as a timestamp in a batch job*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064557/creating-a-file-name-as-a-timestamp-in-a-batch-job/10116045#10116045), I found that it was a space terminating the filename.

Comment: My script above uses this `set mytime=%mytime: =%` to eliminate that space.

Comment: You can set both colon's and spaces as delimiters `"delims=: "` and it will ignore the space.

Answer (score 78):

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher, using WMIC.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
pause
```

Output example:

```
datestamp: "20200828"
timestamp: "085513"
fullstamp: "2020-08-28_08-55-13"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Great and most reliable solution. Thanks

Comment: This really helped me out, thank you. :)

Comment: It seems that the number after `%dt`, or `%date`, or `%time` is depend on system time format settings. For example: If I use date/time format YYYY-MM-DD then `date:~0,4%` will be number of year but if I use format DD/MM/YYYY then  `date:~0,4%` it will be something else.

Answer (score 13):

See Stack Overflow question *[How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090)*.

Create a file, `date.bat`:

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/:/ " %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a-%%b-%%c)
set mytime=%mytime: =% 
echo %mydate%_%mytime%
```

Run `date.bat`:

```
C:\>date.bat
2012-06-14_12-47-PM
```

UPDATE:

You can also do it with one line like this:

`for /f "tokens=2-8 delims=.:/ " %%a in ("%date% %time%") do set DateNtime=%%c-%%a-%%b_%%d-%%e-%%f.%%g`

Comment: sorry that seems to return an invalid date as well, i got `-06-2012_01`

Comment: Why not just do it all on one line? `for /f "tokens=2-8 delims=.:/ " %%a in ("%date% %time%") do set DateNtime=%%c-%%a-%%b_%%d-%%e-%%f.%%g` This example uses the 24 Hour clock rather than 12 Hours + AM/PM, and includes the miliseconds. If you don't want the miliseconds, just don't use `%%g`.

Comment: hi james i put your answer onto my answer

Comment: This answer assumes the computer is set to US date formatting and doesn't work on other systems without modification

Answer (score 7):

Here's a batch script I made to return a timestamp. An optional first argument may be provided to be used as a field delimiter.
For example:

c:\sys\tmp>timestamp.bat
20160404_144741
c:\sys\tmp>timestamp.bat -
2016-04-04_14-45-25
c:\sys\tmp>timestamp.bat :
2016:04:04_14:45:29

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: put your desired field delimiter here.
:: for example, setting DELIMITER to a hyphen will separate fields like so:
:: yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss
::
:: setting DELIMITER to nothing will output like so:
:: yyyyMMdd_hhmmss
::
SET DELIMITER=%1

SET DATESTRING=%date:~-4,4%%DELIMITER%%date:~-7,2%%DELIMITER%%date:~-10,2%
SET TIMESTRING=%TIME%
::TRIM OFF the LAST 3 characters of TIMESTRING, which is the decimal point and hundredths of a second
set TIMESTRING=%TIMESTRING:~0,-3%

:: Replace colons from TIMESTRING with DELIMITER
SET TIMESTRING=%TIMESTRING::=!DELIMITER!%

:: if there is a preceeding space substitute with a zero
echo %DATESTRING%_%TIMESTRING: =0%
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for /f "tokens=2-8 delims=.:/ " %%a in ("%date% %time: =0%") do set DateNtime=%%c-%%a-%%b_%%d-%%e-%%f.%%g
echo %DateNtime%
```

Or, from the command line:

```
for /f "tokens=2-8 delims=.:/ " %a in ("%date% %time: =0%") do echo %c-%a-%b_%d-%e-%f.%g
```

---

**EDIT:** As per bryce's **non-standard** time/date specs. (`03-Sep-12 9:06:21.54`)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=.:/- " %%a in ("%date% %time%") do (
  if "%%b"=="Jan" set MM=01
  if "%%b"=="Feb" set MM=02
  if "%%b"=="Mar" set MM=03
  if "%%b"=="Apr" set MM=04
  if "%%b"=="May" set MM=05
  if "%%b"=="Jun" set MM=06
  if "%%b"=="Jul" set MM=07
  if "%%b"=="Aug" set MM=08
  if "%%b"=="Sep" set MM=09
  if "%%b"=="Oct" set MM=10
  if "%%b"=="Nov" set MM=11
  if "%%b"=="Dec" set MM=12
  set HH=0%%d
  set HH=!HH:~-2!
  echo 20%%c-!MM!-%%a_!HH!-%%e-%%f.%%g
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows batch log file name in 2018-02-08_14.32.06.34.log format:

```
setlocal
set d=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%
set t=%time::=.% 
set t=%t: =%
set logfile="%d%_%t%.log"

ping localhost -n 11>%1/%logfile%
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

It wants the full time in `DD-MM-YYYY_HH-MM-SS.TT` where TT is the ticks. The exception says it all.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've used a .cmd script I found on the Internet. I hate the way localization normally messes with dates. Anytime you have dates in filenames (or anywhere else, if I may be so bold) I figure you want them in ISO 8601 format:

2015-02-19T14:54:51Z

or something else that has Y M D H M in that order, such as

2015-02-19 14:54

because it fixes the MDY / DMY ambiguity and because it's sortable as text.

I don't know where I got that .cmd script, but it may have been http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-getdate.html, which works beautifully on my YYYY-MM-DD Windows 8.1 and on a M/D/YYYY vanilla install of Windows 7. Both give the same format:

2015-02-09 04:43

Answer (score 0):

BATCH/CMD FILE like **DateAndTime.cmd** (*not in CMD-Console*)

Code:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
(set d=%date:~8,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%) & (set t=%time::=.%) & (set t=!t: =0!) & (set STAMP=!d!__!t!)
```

Create output:

```
echo %stamp%
```

Output:

```
2020-02-25__08.43.38.90
```

Or also possible in for lines in CMD-Console and BATCH/CMD File

```
set d=%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%
set t=%time::=.%
set t=%t: =0%
set stamp=%d%__%t%
```

"Create output" and "Output" same as above