# output file redirection to a log file using batch script with timestamp as file name

Tags: batch-file

We have a script named readfile.pl on windows now i need a batch script to execute this script and redirect the output to a new log file everytime it runs (batch should not delete or modify the previous log file) and the name of the log file should be like log_date_time.txt. For Eg if the readfile.pl script is executed on 24th Aug 2012 @ 10:30AM the log file must be log_20120824_10_30.log. can some one please help me on this.

reafile script is located in d:\ and log file location is c:\readlogs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filename timestamp in batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037831/filename-timestamp-in-batch-script)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are going for but try this.

```
command >>log_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%.log
```

What I get when I ECHO that command.

```
log_20120922_10_33.log
```