# VS2015, how to add TimeStamp to the output directory name?

Tags: visual-studio, build-time

I am using VS2015, common C++ project. Is it possible to add current time or date or timestamp to the name of the output directory?

For example: I press the "Build" button at 15:23:45 and the .exe file outputs to the /bin/2016_02_29-15_23_45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution is to add a post-build event running a script adding a folder link named with your timestamp and targeting the output folder.

For the timestamp, follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037831/filename-timestamp-in-windows-cmd-batch-script)

Something like that :

```
 set timestamp= ...
 mklink /D %timestamp% %1
```

Invoke this script passing as first the wanted vs2015 var, `myscript.bat ${OUTPUTFOLDER}`

NB: You may need to have admin permissions to invoke `mklink`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we are using your solution now. But I am interested if it is possible to do only via Visual Studio without external scripts. Mark as accepted unless there will be a more appropriate answer.