# MS-DOS timestamp in filename

Tags: windows, dos

I have the following in a batch file.

```
set timefmt=%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%

dir *.* > logfile_%timefmt%.log
```

This works perfectly after 10am, but fails before hand because it adds a space to the timestamp instead of a leading 0.

Is there a way in MS-DOS to create a time stamp with a leading 0?
I'd prefer to use fairly standard commands so that it works from Windows XP onward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's best to get the time once and then parse the elements, too.
The third line will replace a space with a 0

```
set timefmt=%time%
set timefmt=%TIMEFMT:~0,2%%TIMEFMT:~3,2%%TIMEFMT:~6,2%
set timefmt=%TIMEFMT: =0%
dir *.* > logfile_%timefmt%.log
```

Comment: Point noted about grabbing the time first before doing string manipulation. That is best practice in all languages.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, but I have computers with different locale (some show yyyy-mm-dd for the date, some mm/dd/yyyy).  Some show 12-hour clock with AM and PM, others 24-hour clock...

...so I ended up putting together [a tool for saving the current date/timestamp in an environment variable](https://github.com/HarryPehkonen/dos-timestamp).  Actually, the tool just prints out the timestamp, but there is an example of how to get it into an environment variable:

```
for /f %%x in ('@timestamp.exe') do set TIMESTAMP=%%x
```

...and then you just use %TIMESTAMP% in any way you want.

Answer (score 1):

[Creating a file name as a timestamp in a batch job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064557/creating-a-file-name-as-a-timestamp-in-a-batch-job) has quite a few answers to a problem close to this one. I insert this remark here because Google brought this answer first so that users who are in a hurry might miss the other thread.

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem too.

so I did this. this got me over the hurdle.


:STEP_DATESTAMP

::

REM Setting Datestamp to YYYYMMDD

set v_datestampYYYY=%date:~6,4%

set v_datestampMM=%date:~3,2%

set v_datestampDD=%date:~0,2%

set v_datestamp=%v_datestampYYYY%%v_datestampMM%%v_datestampDD%

::

REM Setting Timestamp to HHMMSS

set HH=%time:~0,2%

:: ensure that hour is always 2 digits

if %HH%==0 set HH=00

if %HH%==1 set HH=01

if %HH%==2 set HH=02

if %HH%==3 set HH=03

if %HH%==4 set HH=04

if %HH%==5 set HH=05

if %HH%==6 set HH=06

if %HH%==7 set HH=07

if %HH%==8 set HH=08

if %HH%==9 set HH=09

set MM=%time:~3,2%

set SS=%time:~6,2%

set v_timestamp=%HH%-%MM%-%SS%