# How can I create a new unique name jmeter.log file each time a CLI command is run?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-logging

Whenever I run a new jmeter command from the CLI a new jmeter.log file is generated and I lose the contents written by the previous test run.

Example:

First I run the test script with :

```
jmeter -n -p .\config.properties -t .\path\to\jmeterScripFile.jmx -l .\path\to\jmeterScriptOutputFile.jtl
```

This generates a fresh jmeter.log file.

Then I run this command to generate a HTML Dashboard report:

```
jmeter -g  .\path\to\jmeterScriptOutputFile.jtl  -o .\path\to\TestResults\ReportHTML
```

This 2nd command overrides the previous jmeter.log file contents.

I would like each jmeter CLI command to generate a unique .log file.
Something like jmeter-yyyymmdd-hhMMss

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can override the default `jmeter.log` file name using [`-j` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like

   ```
   jmeter -j your-custom-log-name-here.log -n -t .....
   ```

   the timestamp can be added by means of your operating system
2. If you want to make the change permanent and don't want to provide the new log file name via `-j` command-line argument you can amend the log file prefix via [*log4j2.xml* file](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/manual/configuration.html) like

   change this line:

   ```
   <File name="jmeter-log" fileName="${sys:jmeter.logfile:-jmeter.log}" append="false">
   ```

   to something like:

   ```
   <File name="jmeter-log" fileName="jmeter-${date:yyyyMMdd-hh-mm-ss}.log" append="false">
   ```

   More information: [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)

Comment: For point 1, any idea how the timestamp can be added when running on Windows command prompt CLI?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter command line option `-j` will allow you to specify the jmeter log file. Name of the file can be set dynamically. If you are on Mac `$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)` can be used for getting the timestamp.

> -j
> [name of JMeter run log file].

[List of command line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)

You can use following command with current time stamps suffix to the jmeter log file. The log file will be create in your JMETER_HOME/bin folder.

```
 ./jmeter -n -t TestPlan-Basic-Test.jmx -j jmeter-$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).log -l test-result.csv
```

Similar could be used on widows. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064557/creating-a-file-name-as-a-timestamp-in-a-batch-job/10116045#10116045)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this simple example the date here generates date now:

```
jmeter -g  ./path/to/"`date`".jtl  -o ./path/to/TestResults/ReportHTML
```

**Extra:**
In case you want dates separated by underscores you can use this

```
DN="`date`"
DATE_NOW=${DN// /_}
jmeter -g  ./path/to/$DATE_NOW.jtl  -o ./path/to/TestResults/ReportHTML
```

**PS**: Don't forget to do the same thing for the other command.

Date Example would look something like this `Sun_Dec__5_00:55:38_WCAST_2021`